# Making third-party API call inside API Handler in Go

Tags: go

I'm building an API route that needs to make a request to a completely separate external API in Go. I have it working up to the point where I try to send a response back to my client, at which time the server does not respond at all. Here's a very minimal example of what I'm doing:

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // ... get request body, etc.

    // Make the external API call here:
    client := &http.Client{}
    url := "https://some_api.com"
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil || resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        fmt.Println("error")
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // ... Process the response from the external call
    
    // Send a response back to my own API's client
    w.Write([]byte("hello there"))
}
```

I'm getting into the handler just fine. I make the API request to some_api.com and get data back, no problem. No errors at all. The problem is that `w.Write()` is not sending anything back to the client.

If I were to put `w.Write([]byte("hi there"))` and immediately return **before** the call do `client.Do`, that works and sends the text back to the client.

What's going on here? I've tried isolating the problem as much as I can but I can't get any errors to actually show. `w.Write` just does nothing if it's after the external API call.

## Edit 1

I tried simplifying the code even further to narrow down the issue, but I'm still not able to get this to succeed. Let me try to be more specific on how I'm calling all of this:

In my **handler**, I have this code:

```
    func sendJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, status int, message string, data interface{}) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(status)
        err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&APIResponse{
            Status: status,
            Message: message,
            Data: data,
        })
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
    }

    func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        myLib := my_lib.New(token, secret)
        account := "512" // Don't worry about this value
        if account == "" {
            // NOTE: This works if account is empty
            sendJSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, "Invalid request", nil)
            return
        }
        events, err := myLib.GetEvents(account, "2023-09-01", "2023-10-31")
        if err != nil {
            // NOTE: This does NOT happen because there's no error
            fmt.Println("there's an error")
            sendJSON(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, "Internal server error", nil)
        }
        fmt.Println(events) // This DOES work and prints the data from the external API
       
        // And finally, this never happens if it runs after GetEvents runs.
        sendJSON(w, http.StatusOK, "Here's the data!", events)
```

And here's the GetEvents method from myLib

```
    func New(token string, secret string) *API {
        return &API{
            client: &http.Client{
                Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
            },
            token: token,
            secret: secret,
        }
    }

    func (o *API) GetEvents(account string, startDate string, endDate string) ([]Event, error) {
        BaseUrl := "http://external-api.com"
        url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/v2/client/%s/event?startDate=%s&endDate=%s", BaseUrl, account, startDate, endDate)
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
        req.Header.Add("token", o.Token)
        req.Header.Add("secret", o.Secret)

        // The line that breaks it all:
        resp, err := o.client.Do(req)
        fmt.Println(resp) // This prints the data from the API successfully

        // For simplicity sake in this code sample I'm just returning an empty array here.
        return []Event{}, err
    }
```

Comment: Maybe there's nothing to write. Show the code that processes the external response and passes the result to write.

Comment: Also; don't do `fmt.Println("error")` and then just continue like nothing happened.

Comment: Perhaps the function returns or panics in the process response code.  Test by moving the call to w.Write immediately following the call to client.Do.

Comment: I'd bet on what @CharlieTumahai said: `err` is not `nil` meaning `resp` is `nil`, and since the `if` statement let the execution go, the handler's code panics likely when calculating the argument to pass to the `defer`red call (when trying to get `Body` out of `nil` pointer which `resp` is). It also might panic _in_ the deferred call while the data written to `w` had yet no chance to be flushed to the client. Do what Charlie said (and also see whether your service prints something to its stderr as IIRC that's what `net/http` does when it traps a panic in a handler).

Comment: @CharlieTumahai I've tested by commenting out everything after the `client.Do` call, effectively putting the `w.Write` immediately after it. If `client.Do` is called, the `w.Write` *will get called* but not send data back to the client.

Comment: @kostix That makes sense, but I don't think anything panics because I'm able to print the response from the external API without any errors. Interesting that you said `net/http` prints to its stderr. How would I print that instead of stdout?

Comment: One more question: does if work if you comment out both the whole `if` statement and the `defer`? Are you sure the client is not closing the connection due to some sort of timeout (I mean, it does not wait enough so that the call to the API manages to complete in time)?

Comment: «How would I print that instead of stdout?»–if you mean "how do I print anything to stderr (in a handler)?" then the answer is to use `fmt.Fprint*(os.Stderr, ...)` or `log.*` which by default print to stderr.

Comment: @kostix Nope, still doesn't work after commenting out the if-statement and defer. Once the `client.Do` line is called the response will no longer send.

Comment: Mark, are you _sure_ client.Do returns (in a sensible amont of time)? What if you `panic` right after it? Does the client get 500?

Comment: @kostix doing a `panic` right after that line didn't make a difference. it did panic but still didn't return to the client. I just made an edit with more code. Please take a look and let me know if you see anything weird. Thanks!

Comment: (Not finished pondering yet), but your `sendJSON` is incorrect: a call to `http.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader` "sets in stone" the HTTP status of the response–by physically sending the so-called ["status line"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) to the client. So, if you later on–that is, when, say, generating and streaming the response's body,–decide there's a fatal error, you can only abort the response completely (which would result in tearing down of the underlying TCP connection) by panicking with `http.ErrAbortHandler`. That is, you cannot `http.Error`, as you do.

Comment: Does `err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&APIResponse{…` in `sendJSON` finish w/o returning an error?

Comment: Yes, the sendJSON method finishes without any errors. `err` is `nil` and the function ends successfully.

Comment: Well, I figured it out. I was hyper-focused on the request to the external API and didn't realize I set the `ReadTimeout` for the main API to 10 seconds. The request takes ~13 seconds to run so it was timing out on my end. Thanks for all of your help with this.

Comment: Good! Still, please consider what I wrote about the error handling in `sendJSON`–it's currently broken (in a non-obvious way). Basically, you cannot communicate an error to your client once you've told them their request succeeded. Also consider what would happen if you'd use a non-stock JSON encoder which would not perform full buffering as the one in `encoding/json` does: I mean, a problem with encoding could be detected in the middle of streaming the response's body into the client. You cannot just somehow interrupt that process and report an error: HTTP is not prepared for _that_ ;-)

Comment: Also please note that the handler code is also currently broken (as presented under "Edit 1") as it still allows the execution to proceed even if `err != nil`. This might be an artifact of preparing an MCVE, but note that in real life cases for "falling past" a non-nil error are rare–off the top of my mind it's file I/O, when a Write or a Read might succeed partially–write and read less bytes than requested, but greater than zero, and return an error. In most cases an error means an operation failed completely and the other return values are unusable.

Answer (score -1):

Need to unmarshal response into Map/json and also add content-type in header while making third party api request.
note:-(headers depends on third party api whether it require json/form/url-encoded/...)

for response use `json.NewEncoder()` returns a new encoder that writes to w

try below code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)



func handlePostRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    client := &http.Client{}
    method := "GET"

    url := "https://some/api/path"
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        
    }
    
    jsonMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    _ = json.Unmarshal(body, &jsonMap)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(jsonMap)
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/post", handlePostRequest)
    fmt.Println("hii")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

second suggestion:-

use context for timeout and channels for communicate response .

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func makeReq(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, res chan<- string) {

    client := &http.Client{}
    url := "https://some/api/path"
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil || resp.StatusCode != 200 {
        fmt.Println("error")
        res <- "error"
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    // w.Write([]byte("hello"))
    res <- "hello"
    return

}
func handlePostRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*3)
    defer cancel()
    respChannel := make(chan string, 1)
    defer close(respChannel)
    go makeReq(w, r, respChannel)
    select {
    case <-time.After(2 * time.Second):
        w.Write([]byte("Process Timeout"))
        return
    case <-ctx.Done():
        w.Write([]byte("Process Timeout"))
        return
    default:
        w.Write([]byte(<-respChannel))
        return
    }

}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/post", handlePostRequest)
    fmt.Println("hii")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I simplified the code greatly for posting here, but you can still send just plain text with `w.Write`, so that's what I included in my code sample. I am actually sending JSON in the real code but it isn't necessary to include that since neither works. The suggestions above don't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: added another suggestion in answer hope it will work.